# Is it possible to run a Job using Cron expression just for the current day in Java using Quartz api

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

Say for example i want to run a job for a day at "3:22, 4:22, 6:22, 10:22, 18:22, 21.22" on these times just for the current day.

How could we write a cron expresion for it or using other Simple Trigger of Quartz API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cron trigger you can set endAt() to stop trigger at the end of the day

```
  trigger = newTrigger()
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule(0 22 3,4,6,10,18,21 ? * * *))
    .endAt(TRIGGER_END_TIME)
    .forJob(myJobKey)
    .build();
```

Comment: Thank you so much @vamsikurre....Just what i needed...really appreciate it a lot.